# dynamic breadcrumbs responding with a sidebar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, breadcrumbs

I have a sidebar to filter people with some parameters, like city and sex. I need breadcrumbs so that when I click on a sex or city it desplegate the new breadcrumb, but also it has to save the previous parameter. Like this:

```
Home / sex / male / city / NY
```

but I have a jquery code that do this:

```
Home  / Sex /male (and when i click on city it does this:)

Home / City / NY (it erase the other)
```

I leave the code here:

```
  $('.items label').on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this),
  $bc = $('<div class="item"></div>');

  $this.parents('li').each(function(n, li) {
      var $a = $(li).children('label').clone();
      ($a.addClass("btn btn-default")).removeAttr("style margin-left");
      $bc.prepend($a);
  });
    $('.btn-breadcrumb').html( $bc.prepend('<a href="#Home" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></a>') );
    return false;
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mPsez/3/ this is a example that I get from this page.  The problem with this code is the same that I have; it erases the previous when you click on test1, test2, or test3.

Comment: Looks like it is working fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//If we click on the anchor...
$('.items a').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $bc = $(".breadcrumb");

    //We store the current path on the breadcrumb.
    var previousValue = $bc.html();

    //We delete the content of the breadcrumb.
    $bc.html("");

    //For each li item...
    $this.parents('li').each(function (n, li) {
        //we make a copy of the child anchor as we will want the same behaviour on our
        //breadcrumb.
        var $a = $(li).children('a').clone();
        //and we attach the clone after the previous clone if there is any. We also
        //insert a separator.
        $bc.append(' / ', $a);
    });

    //Once we are done we attach our old value to the beginning of the breadcrumb.
    $bc.prepend(previousValue);

    //and we cancel the default behaviour of the anchor.
    return false;
})
```

Basically I stored the previous value, deleted the breadcrumb and joint the old with the new value.

Comment: Thanks Mario, but can you replace the parameters with the parameters that i have, cause i'm new using jquery and i dont realize what i have to replace.

Comment: Well, the important change is the part where you store the old value and merge it with the new one but all the code I gave you replace totally yours. Instead applying the listener to the label as you did I applied to the anchor and changed the layout of your menu.